# why is my gradle build failing but gradlew build is successsful?

Tags: java, gradle, war

I have a gradle project that I am trying to build.

when I execute `gradle clean build`, it fails with the following error message

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':FacebookUpdateDependencies'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compiler'.
   > Could not resolve com.company.facebook:compiler:1.2+.
     Required by:
         ::1.0
      > Could not resolve com.company.facebook:compiler:1.2+.
         > Failed to list versions for com.company.facebook:compiler.
            > Unable to load Maven meta-data from http://mycompanynexus/compiler/maven-metadata.xml.
               > Could not GET 'http://mycompanynexus/compiler/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 500 from server: Internal Server Error
```

However, when I tried
`./gradlew clean build` the build is successful.

why the build fails in the former and not the latter?

here is revelant portion of build.gradle

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.11'
}
```

**EDIT**

```
local$: gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.13
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2016-04-25 04:10:10 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     3b427b1481e46232107303c90be7b05079b05b1c

Groovy:       2.4.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.7.0_79 (Oracle Corporation 24.79-b02)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.11.1 x86_64

local$ ./gradlew -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.12
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2014-04-29 09:24:31 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     a831fa866d46cbee94e61a09af15f9dd95987421

Groovy:       1.8.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
Ivy:          2.2.0
JVM:          1.7.0_79 (Oracle Corporation 24.79-b02)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.11.1 x86_64
```

Comment: I think, `gradlew` is the previous version that has been done successfully, the current build fails and cannot generate a new wrapper

Comment: looks like gradlew and gradle are using different versions of gradle, but why it fails connecting to the repo. The error does not seem to reflect the version issues\

Comment: The wrapper is only generated when executing `gradle wrapper` and not on every build. You should probably try to generate a new wrapper as the current wrapper's version differs from the one specified in the build file. Is `mycompanynexus` the real name of the repository server or has it been edited for this question?

Comment: It may be related to different network settings used by the two different versions of gradle. The gradle home of the wrapper is typically the `gradle/wrapper` directory in your root project. There are perhaps some additional settings in properties file, that are only used by the wrapper and not by the "regular" version of gradle.

Comment: What's interesting with the output of the two gradle version is, that the installed gradle doesn't print any ivy version. Maybe the installed gradle is missing some ivy component used for dependency resolution, that is available in the gradle wrapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just noticed that the wrapper version is `1.12` and not `2.12`. That is, there is a very large version difference between the wrapper and the installed version of gradle. There have probably been many incompatible changes to the different gradle plugins over the last 2 years, which may lead to the build problems you observe.

As already mentioned the gradle wrapper is a separate version of gradle that resides in the `gradle/wrapper` folder of your project. The wrapper is only built/updated, when executing the `wrapper` task in your project (`gradle wrapper`). That is your project's wrapper has not been updated for the last 2 years or has been created with the wrong version initially (`1.12` instead of `2.11`).

Given the above it's hard the tell what is actually causing the build to fail - apart from the incompatibilities between gradle `1.12` and `2.13`. But this version mismatch is probably the root cause of your problem.

Most likely your project won't built anymore using the wrapper once you regenerated the wrapper with version `2.11` (the version mentioned in the build file), as `2.11` is likely to be incompatible to `1.12` as well...

Answer (score 1):

This tells you that your Gradle version 2.11 will be used when `gradlew` command is invoked instead of the one installed on system.  Always run `gradlew` command as it ensures your build is run against the gradle version it is supposed to, you are never required to install the correct version of gradle and really speeds up the build time.

Here is an excerpt from Gradle Wrapper definition:

> Most tools require installation on your computer before you can use them. If the installation is easy, you may think that’s fine. But it can be an unnecessary burden on the users of the build. Equally importantly, will the user install the right version of the tool for the build? What if they’re building an old version of the software?
>
> The Gradle Wrapper (henceforth referred to as the “Wrapper”) solves both these problems and is the preferred way of starting a Gradle build.
>   If a Gradle project has set up the Wrapper (and we recommend all projects do so), you can execute the build using one of the following commands from the root of the project:

./gradlew  (on Unix-like platforms such as Linux and Mac OS X)
gradlew  (on Windows using the gradlew.bat batch file)
Each Wrapper is tied to a specific version of Gradle, so when you first run one of the commands above for a given Gradle version, it will download the 
corresponding Gradle distribution and use it to execute the build.

Comment: No, it tells us that the wrapper version doesn't match the version in the build file. Probably the wrapper has not been generated again after setting the version to 2.11. However this does not explain why the project can't be built with the installed version of gradle.

Comment: In regards to the above comment, try running this.
`gradle wrapper --gradle-version 2.11`

Followed by 
`gradle clean build`